# How to solve segmentation fault problems happening in support libraries?

Tags: c++, c, openssl, segmentation-fault

I have a very odd problem going on. I can replicate the problem by the following small sample code:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <iostream>

void printSSLErrors()
{
    int l_err = ERR_get_error();
    while(l_err!=0)
    {
      std::cout << "SSL ERROR: " << ERR_error_string(l_err, NULL) << std::endl;
      l_err = ERR_get_error();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    // context
    SSL_CTX* mp_ctx;

    if(!(mp_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method())))
    {
      printSSLErrors();
      return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "CTX created OK" << std::endl;

    // set certificate and private key
    if(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(mp_ctx, argv[1], SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)!=1)
    {
      printSSLErrors();
      return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Certificate intialised OK" << std::endl;

    if(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(mp_ctx, argv[2], SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)!=1)
    {
      printSSLErrors();
      return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Key intialised OK" << std::endl;

    SSL_CTX_free(mp_ctx);
    ERR_free_strings();
}
```

This program works as expected when I compile it and link it using `-lssl`. The problem however is that the openssl routines are part of an application that also links in the mysqlclient libraries. I now recompile the above code with `-lssl -lmysqlclient` (note that I don't include or use anything from that library here). If I execute the program again I get a segmentation fault in the open ssl library. The most I can pull out of gdb is:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread -1208158528 (LWP 32359)]
CTX created OK
Certificate intialised OK

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread -1208158528 (LWP 32359)]
0x001b1213 in X509_get_pubkey () from /lib/libcrypto.so.4

(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x001b1213 in X509_get_pubkey () from /lib/libcrypto.so.4
#1  0x00de8a6c in SSL_rstate_string () from /lib/libssl.so.4
#2  0x086f2258 in ?? ()
#3  0xbffceb64 in ?? ()
#4  0x086f1130 in ?? ()
#5  0xbffceaa8 in ?? ()
#6  0x086f2258 in ?? ()
#7  0x086f0d90 in ?? ()
#8  0x00df4858 in ?? () from /lib/libssl.so.4
#9  0x086f2258 in ?? ()
#10 0x086f1130 in ?? ()
#11 0xbffceaa8 in ?? ()
#12 0x00de9d50 in SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file () from /lib/libssl.so.4
Previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) frame 0
#0  0x001b1213 in X509_get_pubkey () from /lib/libcrypto.so.4
```

For some reason this only happens when I use mysqlclient v 15 and not with mysqlclient v 16.  This is probably too obscure for anyone to solve, but some comments on how linking against a dynamic library that the code itself doesn't even use can cause these errors would be very helpful.

The system is:

RHEL ES4, gcc 3.4.6, openssl-0.9.7a, MySQL-5.11

Any thoughts?

Edit: Here is the output to possibly clarify things a little more:

```
[Lieuwe ~]$ c++ openssl_test.cpp -lssl -o ssltest 
[Lieuwe ~]$ ./ssltest /etc/httpd/conf/certs/test.crt /etc/httpd/conf/certs/test.key 
CTX created OK
Certificate intialised OK
Key intialised OK
[Lieuwe ~]$ c++ openssl_test.cpp -lmysqlclient -lssl -o ssltest 
[Lieuwe ~]$ ./ssltest /etc/httpd/conf/certs/test.crt /etc/httpd/conf/certs/test.key 
CTX created OK
Certificate intialised OK
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[Lieuwe ~]$
```

Note that for this purpose I use the crt and key file that the apache server also uses (and work)

Edit 2: Here is the (relevant?) output of valgrind for the program

```
CTX created OK
--5429-- REDIR: 0x5F6C80 (memchr) redirected to 0x4006184 (memchr)
Certificate intialised OK
==5429== Invalid read of size 4
==5429==    at 0xCF4205: X509_get_pubkey (in /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xDE8A6B: (within /lib/libssl.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xDE9D4F: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file (in /lib/libssl.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0x8048C77: main (in /home/liwu/ssltest)
==5429==  Address 0x4219940 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 84 free'd
==5429==    at 0x4004EFA: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:235)
==5429==    by 0xC7FD00: CRYPTO_free (in /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xCE53A7: (within /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xCE5562: ASN1_item_free (in /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xCE0560: X509_free (in /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xDE979E: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file (in /lib/libssl.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0x8048C23: main (in /home/liwu/ssltest)
==5429== 
==5429== Invalid read of size 4
==5429==    at 0xCD4A5F: EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters (in /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xDE8A7C: (within /lib/libssl.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xDE9D4F: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file (in /lib/libssl.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0x8048C77: main (in /home/liwu/ssltest)
==5429==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5429== 
==5429== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5429==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==5429==    at 0xCD4A5F: EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters (in /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xDE8A7C: (within /lib/libssl.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0xDE9D4F: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file (in /lib/libssl.so.0.9.7a)
==5429==    by 0x8048C77: main (in /home/liwu/ssltest)
==5429==
```

Comment: build with debug symbols and see what really happens

Comment: Have you verified that `argc >= 3` upon testing? That verification should be in your code.

Comment: The only thing I see for now is that you use argv[] without checking if enough arguments are available. This could possibly lead to problems.

Comment: This is just a small test program to replicate the segmentation fault - the arguments are there & given.  I am building with debug symbols - but obviously the openssl libraries I use are not.

Comment: ok, link with debug openssl libraries

Comment: I suggest you take @thkala's advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running your program under [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/). Valgrind is intended to provide help with exactly this kind of problem and it is generally much easier to use than a debugger.

If I were to hazard a guess, I would first suspect a memory error in your application (or, less likely, in one of the shared libraries) that is sensitive to the memory layout of the resulting executable. Adding a new shared library or, say, enabling debugging options could very well make the problem appear or disappear for no apparent reason.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would a memory error on my part not show up in the code I posted (which is all that is needed to reproduce the behaviour)? I ran the program under valgrind - I switched on the verbose flag and it tells me a very similar thing - I added the (relevant) output to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The only logical explanation may be that the public key, which is needed for X509_get_pubkey(), can not be located.

Can you please verify that the public key requested by the function is available?

Comment: They are definitely available.

Comment: After a small search I did on the source code, the following lines of code are executed: 
    EVP_PKEY *X509_get_pubkey(X509 *x)
 {
 if ((x == NULL) || (x->cert_info == NULL))
  return(NULL);
 return(X509_PUBKEY_get(x->cert_info->key));
 }
 Also, the structure X509 that is used in order to call the method is created inside SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(). Hence I believe that some object is missing, or you can try running it with root privileges.

Comment: Thanks for thinking. Running as root makes no difference. The odd thing is that linking against an unrelated (and unused) library actually causes this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that the mysql client library is linked against another version of libssl. If you are on linux: are both libraries installed via your distro's official repositories? Are you linking against the static (.a) or dynamic (.so) versions of those libraries?

You can play around with the `nm` command to find out more (read the manpage).

You can try to rebuild the mysql client library yourself to make sure the same libssl version is used and see whether the problem disappears.